# Compatibility Mode error when installing Visual Studio SDK (vssdk)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to install the Visual Studio SDK I get the following error:

```
Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try Setup again.
```

[image: error]

I have checked and Compatibility mode is not turned on.  From what I've read, renaming the installer to `vssdk_full.exe` should help.  That hasn't had any impact.

I got the installer from [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758).

What do I need to do to get this to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you installing on Windows 10? If so, then I have the same problem and it seems as though the current SDK setup is checking the Windows version and 10 isn't currently supported. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77c61be0-1303-4040-a587-62843d321159/visual-studio-2013-sdk?forum=WinPreview2014General for more info

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to get it to install on windows 10, download the sdk, it will download vssdk_full.exe, run this with /layout path which will extract the actual setup file.

Then set compatibility on the new file to win 8 and it will install just fine.

You might not need to do the/layout thing but that is what I did.

ed

Comment: My success was from using `/layout`, and I didn't need to run the resulting file with any compatibility settings.

Comment: I am sorry but what do we mean by /layout?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I downloaded .iso file with install package form the internet. Then I mounted it using PowerISO and tried to start it from virtual CD drive. It ended up in the same message as above.

I looked it up and thought that in Properties of .exe install file, it's enough to uncheck some boxes compability section. But nothing was checked.

Soon afterwards I unzipped the package to a temporary directory with PowerISO and installed Visual from there. Worked without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I renamed the instalation file to "vssdk_full.exe" and it installed without problems.